# bind 9.9.4 rndc: connection to remote host closed

Tags: linux, dns, bind, domain

I have installed `bind-9.9.4-72` on CentOS 7.6 and everything seems working i can query my local zone and remote address etc. but somehow `rndc` not working

This is what i did to configure `rndc`

`rndc-confgen > /tmp/rndc.out`

and created two files from above output.

rndc.conf

```
# Start of rndc.conf
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "9da1tS0degu3ZfVIVRO/Dg==";
};

options {
    default-key "rndc-key";
    default-server 127.0.0.1;
    default-port 953;
};
# End of rndc.conf
```

rndc.key

```
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "9da1tS0degu3ZfVIVRO/Dg==";
};
```

named.conf

```
    controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1; 10.30.0.50;} keys { "rndc-key"; };
    };

include "/etc/rndc.key";
```

Getting following Error

```
[root@ns1 etc]# rndc status
rndc: connection to remote host closed
This may indicate that
* the remote server is using an older version of the command protocol,
* this host is not authorized to connect,
* the clocks are not synchronized,
* the the key signing algorithm is incorrect, or
* the key is invalid.
```

Detail outout

```
[root@ns1 etc]# rndc -V status
create memory context
create socket manager
create task manager
create task
create logging context
setting log tag
creating log channel
enabling log channel
create parser
get key
decode base64 secret
status
post event
using server 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1#953)
create socket
bind socket
connect
create message
render message
schedule recv
send message
rndc: connection to remote host closed
```

log file..

```
Dec 18 14:05:34 ns1 named[18947]: invalid command from 127.0.0.1#47203: failure
Dec 18 14:05:58 ns1 named[18947]: invalid command from 127.0.0.1#54722: failure
Dec 18 14:05:59 ns1 named[18947]: invalid command from 127.0.0.1#32822: failure
Dec 18 14:06:03 ns1 named[18947]: invalid command from 127.0.0.1#56079: failure
```

I have also verified rndc and bind running on same version.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution:

If named cannot find the rndckey in /etc/rndc.key, it will report the `error 'rndc: connection to remote host closed'`.

When using `rndc-confgen -a` to create a new rndc key, the new key will be called rndc-key by default. Therefore, the `/etc/rndc.key` file will need to be edited and the key name changed to *rndckey* ( remove any `-` ) for the sake of named. Likewise the command:

`rndc-confgen -a -k rndckey`

make sure `/etc/rndc.key` is a soft link to `/var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key`

`ln -s /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key /etc/.`

```
[root@ns1 etc]# rndc status
version: 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-72.el7 <id:8f9657aa>
CPUs found: 2
worker threads: 2
UDP listeners per interface: 2
number of zones: 208
debug level: 0
xfers running: 0
xfers deferred: 0
soa queries in progress: 0
query logging is ON
recursive clients: 0/0/1000
tcp clients: 0/100
server is up and running
```

Comment: I had the error `invalid command from 127.0.0.1#47119: failure` and your clue about the key was right. My use case is Virtualmin with cluster slave servers running on Ubuntu and after a stock install I got that error. The commands to check rndc helped a lot. The solution was change algorithm from `hmac-sha256;` to `hmac-md5;`